# Communication between the standalone Java service and Tomcat8 through JMS

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jms

Is it possible to create a Communication between the standalone Java service and Tomcat8 through JMS?

I need that standalone service act as a Publisher and Tomcat as a Subscriber. 
External devices send data over a socket connection on standalone service. Once the message is received and parsed, the service sends it to Tomcat.
I don't want to use DB for this communication.

Please send examples of the implementation. Preferred Spring JMS but not mandatory.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want "Tomcat as a subscriber" are you expecting tomcat to do something if it receives a message from the service via JMS?

Comment: Thank you for replay @HimanshuBhardwaj. Yes. I would like to send new data over web socket/comet connection on client side.

Comment: So that's not Tomcat which is going to subscribe rather your web-application which is deployed in tomcat is going to subscribe to JMS. You can refer to any example available online. There is nothing fancy in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doable with or without Spring JMS. Main point is that you would need to host JMS server somewhere anyway. Let say you are using ActiveMQ server.

You will need to add dependencies on ActiveMQ client libraries into both of your projects (Tomcat8 and standalone Jar). You can use Spring JMS in both projects.

Than you create queue in your Active MQ server.

Your sender application will use ActiveMQ client libraries to send the messages to created queue.
Your Tomcat8 application will register listener on created queue using ActiveMQ client libraries.

**EDIT**

Here are links I suggest to follow:

- [Installation section of ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html). Don't know your prefered system, so pick by yourself. It is very easy to install it.
- [Official Spring guide for creating JMS project](http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/). Use sending part for your standalone project and listener part for your Tomcat8 application.

Comment: Thanks @lkrnac. But I need some links on examples.

Comment: Thank you @lkrnac. I read the book abount ActiveMQ and now it is clear.